# JS slidetoggle on UL Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, html-lists, jquery-ui-accordion

When i click on second item with slideToggle, first item close.

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggleSitemap').find('ul').css('display','none')
    $('.toggleSitemap').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qHZsZ/2/

Comment: ok , exactly as you described..

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how much will this help you. I also needed to implement accordian(toggle) in my MVC project once, and I used something like this:
   View.aspx:

```
  <div class='toggle' style="float: left">
    <div style="float: left;clear:both;">
    <br />
        <span class="ulGroup" jqattr="<%:Group.Key %>" style="font-weight: bold;font-color: black;cursor: pointer"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/Images/imageplus.gif")%>"/>
            <%:Group.Key%></span>
    </div>
    <div class="togglebox" style="clear:both;" >

       <!-- Write contents as you wish -->
       <!-- as
       <ul> test
         <li>Test1></li>
         <li>Test2></li>
         <li>Test3></li>
       </ul>
       .
       .
       .
        -->

    </div>
 </div>
```

And called a design.js (javascript file) as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Hide the tooglebox when page load 
$(".togglebox").hide();

//slide up and down when click over span
$(".ulGroup").click(function () {
    var valueText = $(this).attr('jqAttr');

    // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
     var x = $(this).parent().next(".togglebox").css("display");

    if (x == "block") {
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($('<img src="../../Images/imageplus.gif"/>'))
        $(this).append(' ' + valueText);
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('');
        $(this).append($('<img src="../../Images/imageplus.gif"/>'))
        $(this).append(' ' + valueText);
    }
    $(this).parent().next(".togglebox").slideToggle("fast");
    return true;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. I think the key ingredient you're missing is to prevent propagation of the click event.

Also, to make it a little less quirky, you only want the click event to fire if the target's direct parent has the `toggleSitemap` class.

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggleSitemap').click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass('toggleSitemap')) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/DkbNA/2/**